# Rate of spontaneous emission and energy conservation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, photon-emission

The english wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission#Rate_of_spontaneous_emission (26.08.2020, 16:45) gives the rate for spontaneous emission as
$$
\Gamma_{rad}(\omega) = \frac{\omega^3n|\mu_{12}|^2}{3\pi \varepsilon_0 \hbar c^3}
$$

Isn't this missing some sort of condition for omega to ensure energy conservation like $\delta(\omega - \omega_{12} )$ ? This formula makes it look as if spontaneous emission always has the form of $f(\omega) = k \omega^3$, where $k$ is some constant.

Comment: Perhaps in that formula $\omega$ is the frequency of the transition in question.

Comment: From the same article in a subsequent paragraph *In contrast with atoms, which have a discrete emission spectrum, quantum dots can be tuned continuously by changing their size. This property has been used to check the $\omega^3$-frequency dependence of the spontaneous emission rate as described by Fermi's golden rule.*

Comment: Still, it wouldn't make sense to write it as a function of omega then. It should read along these lines if that is the case, $\Gamma_{12} = \omega_{12}^3|\mu_{12}|^2$, omitting the constants.

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish That only means that the indices are no longer discrete but continuous variables, you still have one fixed frequency for a transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation has to be evaluated at a specific value for $\omega$. For spontaneous emission from electronic state $|i\rangle \rightarrow |f\rangle$ we have to use the the frequency $$\omega = \omega_{if} = (E_i-E_f)/\hbar   $$ and the transition dipole moment magnitude squared $| \mu_{if}|^2$,
$$\begin{aligned}\Gamma^{i\rightarrow f}_{rad} &= \Gamma_{rad}(\omega=\omega_{if}) \\
&= \frac{\omega_{if}^3n|\mu_{if}|^2}{3\pi \varepsilon_0 \hbar c^3} \end{aligned}$$